# Azure Functions Database Connection String

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

How do I add or access an `app.config` file in Azure functions to add a database connection string?

If you're not supposed to add an `app.config` and there is a better way to access an external database to execute the function please let me know best practices.  Thanks!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Jan_V *almost* nailed it, which led me to experiment with this in the `local.settings.json`

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true;",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnectionString": "[YourConnectionStringHere]"
  }
}
```

This allows you to use the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[]` we are all used to.

```
var sqlConnection = ConfigurationManager
                   .ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Nice addition! Definitely more clean

Comment: local.settings.json file is not even uploaded to Azure. how is it supposed to be working? it is file to debug locally I believe

Comment: @batmaci yup, that file is for local debugging only. Since Azure Functions is built on top of App Service, you put your connection strings in the Application Settings area (there's a section for Connection Strings).

Comment: You also need to grab `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` from Nuget to get this to work.

Comment: Found this helpful also: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-function-with-entity-framework/

Answer (score 37):

The best way to do this is to add a Connection String from the Azure portal:

- From your Function App UI, click Function App Settings
- Settings / Application Settings
- Add connection strings

They will then be available using the same logic as if they were in a web.config, e.g.

```
var conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                 .ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString;
```

Or if you're using a non-.NET language, you can use App Settings instead, which become simple environment variables at runtime that your functions can access.

Comment: Almost. This resulted in a "missing assembly" cimpilation error for me. I needed to add #r"System.Configuration" to the top of the file as well.

Comment: Yes, we probably should reference it by default. I'll discuss with others on team.

Comment: FYI I opened https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/374 to track.

Comment: I have the same problem and after spending a long time searching I haven't figured out the solution. Azure just ignores Application Settings and use the connection string from web.config. As I see in the [Channel 9 video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Custom-configuration-and-application-settings-in-Azure-Web-Sites-with-Stefan-Schackow), it would be "magic", but doesn't is.

Comment: @MarceloSader that video is about Azure Web Apps, and this question is about Azure Functions. Maybe you commented on the wrong question?

Comment: Sorry @DavidEbbo, I apologize. By the way, I found out an error on my code. Everything is working fine now. Exactly like I saw on the video.

Comment: @MarceloSader no problem, glad to hear!

Comment: The security is the reason why is better to have such connection string on Azure side and run-time binding. If somebody steal your code he can not access to the database.

Answer (score 31):

Todd De Land's answer only works for local environment. However per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#environment-variables), published Azure Function needs connection strings be stored as app settings and retrieved by `GetEnvironmentVariable`.

Adding `System.Configuration` assembly reference is **unnecessary**.

```
string cs = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyConnectionString",EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Here are the steps to make environment strings retrievable for **both** local and published environment

1. To support local environment, in `local.settings.json`, specify your connection strings inside `Values` node

[image: local.settings.json picture]

2. To support published environment, go to `portal.azure.com > your Azure Function > function node > Application Settings`

[image: Application Settings]

[image: Add MyConnectionString]

3. Finally, call `GetEnvironmentVariable` from your Azure Function (cant get stackoverflow to display this code correctly)

[image]

Thats it.

Comment: you should not be putting database connection strings here they should be in the connection string section of the settings in azure and local.settings.json

Comment: I disagree @Anthony.  When working with ASP.NET core, you are correct. However, Azure functions work a little differently in that they don't inherently support the configuration manager. You can add it in a custom fashion, but it is easier to just throw the connection string into the values object in your local.settings.json.

Comment: Thank you! This is actually the recommended approach for Azure Functions v2

Comment: @Nate Azure Functions support the use of the `ConnectionStrings` section. You can use `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration.GetConnectionString(connStrName)` and place the connection strings in the `ConnectionStrings` section of the config.

Answer (score 29):

Configuration Manager will be replaced by the new Asp.Net Core Configuration System in Functions Runtime v2.

So if you are using .Net Core you should follow John Gallants Blog article:
https://blog.jongallant.com/2018/01/azure-function-config/

- Works with local.settings.json and Settings in Azure Function
- Works with App Settings and Connection Strings

Comment: I needed exactly this, because I am using the new V2 azure functions runtime and .NET Standard runtime. Thx!

Comment: Above article works but you need to add nuget package: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables` otherwise you will get an error about `AddEnvironmentVariables` not existing.

Comment: This is the proper solution, but remember links shouldn't be used in answers.

Answer (score 19):

Addition to the answer from @ToddDeLand.

With a `local.settings.json` like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true;",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnectionString": "[YourConnectionStringHere]"
  }
}
```

You can then access your connection string like this, no NuGets needed.

```
var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString");
```

Microsoft recommends this approach here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#environment-variables

If you add the connection string to values:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true;",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
    "MyConnectionString": "[YourConnectionStringHere]"
  }
}
```

You can access your connection string like this:

```
var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyConnectionString");
```

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52219491/3850405

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/717#issuecomment-400098791

Comment: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString") was what worked for me. Thank you big time!

Answer (score 18):

I went through several similar questions and answers here. Many of them are either misleading or assuming everybody is on the same level and understands how the azure functions are working. there is no answer for newbies like me. I would like to summarize here my solution step by step.

1. most important thing is that we understand local.settings.json file
   IS NOT FOR AZURE. it is to run your app in the local as the name is
   clearly saying. So solution is nothing to do with this file.
2. App.Config or Web.Config doesnt work for Azure function connection strings. If you have Database Layer Library you cant overwrite connection string using any of these as you would do in Asp.Net applications.
3. In order to work with, you need to define your connection string on the azure portal under the `Application Settings` in your Azure function. There is 
   Connection strings. there you should copy your connection string of your DBContext. if it is edmx, it will look like as below. There is Connection type, I use it SQlAzure but I tested with Custom(somebody claimed only works with custom) works with both.

> metadata=res://*/Models.myDB.csdl|res://*/Models.myDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.myDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider
>   connection string='data source=[yourdbURL];initial
>   catalog=myDB;persist security info=True;user
>   id=xxxx;password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework

4. After you set this up, You need to read the url in your application and provide the DBContext. DbContext implements a constructor with connection string parameter. By default constructor is without any parameter but you can extend this. if you are using POCO classes, you can amend the DbContext class simply. If you use Database generated Edmx classes like I do, you don't want to touch the auto generated edmx classes, instead you want to create partial class in the same namespace and extend this class as below.

This is auto generated DbContext

```
namespace myApp.Data.Models
{   

    public partial class myDBEntities : DbContext
    {
        public myDBEntities()
           : base("name=myDBEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

}
```

this is the new partial class, you create

```
namespace myApp.Data.Models
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(myDBContextConfig))]
    partial class myDBEntities
    {

        public myDBEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
    }

      public  class myDBContextConfig : DbConfiguration
        {
            public myDBContextConfig()
            {
                SetProviderServices("System.Data.EntityClient", 
                SqlProviderServices.Instance);
                SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SqlConnectionFactory());
            }
        }
    }
```

5. After all you can get the connection string from azure settings, in your Azure Function project with the code below and provide to your DbContext
   myDBEntities is the name you gave in the azure portal for your connection string.

> ```
> var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDBEntities"].ConnectionString;
>
>
>  using (var dbContext = new myDBEntities(connString))
> {
>         //TODO:
> }
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I believe common practice is use environment variables for azure functions, then you can setup the environment variables in the Azure Function:

(Function App Settings -> Configure app settings -> App settings section)

Maybe would be more helpful if you can also let us know which language you are using?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using function runtime v3, then following approach will work for you.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true;",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnectionString": "[YourConnectionStringHere]"
  }
}
```

In your function's startup file

```
public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
    var config = builder.ConfigurationBuilder.Build();
    var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried below code snippet on my local database that seems easy. Let's have a look.

**Nuget Extention:**

Download following reference from `Nuget Package Manager` On your project `Dependencies` part

```cs
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "sqldb_connection": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Connection Timeout=30;Integrated Security=True;"
  }
}
```

**Read Connection On Function Body:**

//Read database Connection

```
        var sqlConnection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("sqldb_connection");
```

**Function Read Write Operation Using Connection String:**

```cs
// Convert all request perameter into Json object

                var content = req.Content;
                string jsonContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                dynamic requestPram = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureSqlTableClass>(jsonContent);

                // Validate required param

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestPram.FirstName))
                {
                    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Please enter First Name!");
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestPram.LastName))
                {
                    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Please enter Last Name!");
                }



                //Read database Connection

                var sqlConnection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("sqldb_connection");
                var responseResults = 0;

                //Read Write Uisng Connection String

                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var text = "INSERT INTO AzureSqlTable VALUES ('" + requestPram.FirstName + "', '" + requestPram.LastName + "', '" + requestPram.Email + "') ";

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
                    {
                        responseResults = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }

                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseResults);
```

> **Note:** While publish your function on `azure portal` just replace the connection string on `local.settings.json` file. It will work
>   accordingly. See the screen shot below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this method.

```
public static string GetConnectionString(string name)
{
    string conStr = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"ConnectionStrings:{name}", 
                    EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

    // Azure Functions App Service naming 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(conStr))convention
        conStr = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"SQLAZURECONNSTR_{name}", 
                 EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

    return conStr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

some of the above suggestions work. However there is a more straight forward way of setting a connection string. It is by using the 'publish' screen one sees after hitting the publish setting. [see picture from documentation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpsVz.png) 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Best way to handle connection strings is by using "Azure Key Vault". You can store all the important secrets in Key Vault and consume in the Application.
As suggested by other members you can use Application Settings.

help full links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-key-vault-manage-portal?view=azs-2002

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me both locally & in Azure for an http trigger function that queries cosmos db

added [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB) nuget package reference to project

connection string settings:

local.settings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CosmosDBConnection": "AccountEndpoint=foobar;"
  }
}
```

in *Azure portal* > *function apps* > *platform features* > *configurations* > *Application settings* > *New application settings* >
`Name: CosmosDBConnection`   `Value: AccountEndpoint=foobar;`
*update* > *save*

sample c# Azure function

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
           [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequest req,
           [CosmosDB(databaseName:"dbName",
                     collectionName:"collectionName",
                     ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")] DocumentClient documentClient, 
           ILogger log){
             .....
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store connection string in azure key vault and enable MSI on azure function and add access policy on azure key vault to read key value.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions Version 4: How to configure your connection string.

Concepts:

A. There are four versions of Azure Functions. The below was written for version 4. Edit your project file if you are unsure of which version you are using. `<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>`

B. You must configure both the local dev environment, and the server environment separately.  They are different and require different configuration, but the code which uses the configuration will be the same.

C. Use environmental variables. The usual appconfig.json file is not supported in Azure Functions, being a lightweight execution environment. (You could also use AzureKey vault but that is a different topic.)

1. To set your dev environment variable, add it to local.settings.json  Note that this file is NOT published, and applies only to your local machine as the name implies.

   {
   "IsEncrypted": false,
   "Values": {
   "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
   "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
   "DefaultConnectionString":  "MyConnectionString"
   }
   }
2. For your published environment, go into the Azure Portal and set it there.

Comment: Note that all credit for this answer goes to the earlier answers.  I wrote this only to clarify the answer for V4

Answer (score -1):

Having the Connection details in the Key vault and accessing the connection string using the User Assigned Managed Identity is the best approach to connect to the Database.

follow below steps to achieve this.

1. Give the Azure Function User 'Key-Vault-Contributor' role.
2. Add the AZURE_CLIENT_ID in the Configuration as shown below.
   [Configuration of Azure Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zex5J.png)
3. add the below lines to your code.
   credential = DefaultAzureCredential(managed_identity_client_id=client_id)
   keyvault_client = SecretClient(vault_url=key_vault_url, credential=credential)
   Replace 'key_vault_url' with your key vault URL.
4. Now you can use the keyvault_client to get the secret values using below syntax.
   secret_variable = keyvault_client.get_secret("secret-name")

   Replace the Now 'secret-name' with the secret name which you created in azure KeyVault. secret_variable.value can be used in your code where you want to use it for connection.