# Can I make a SQL query and return its result with Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, mysql, azure-functions

I want to port my C# program to MS Azure Functions. It does a SQL-Query and returns the result (an IEnumerable). I want to use it in PowerApps.

Can I do this and how?

Comment: this is a really good question and hasn't been asked before... why did you close it !!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To connect to SQL, you need add a connection string in the app settings. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215069/azure-functions-database-connection-string) for detailed instructions.
Here is sample for HTTPTrigger in CSharp that uses Linq to SQL and returns the result from the query

- Got to Function App Settings --> Go to Kudu --> Go to D:\home\site\wwwroot\YourFunction
- Create folder bin
- Upload System.Data.dll, System.Data.Linq.dll
- Upload following TodoItem.csx either from View Files UI on the portal or Kudu

  ```
  #r "System.Data.Linq.dll"

  using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

  [Table(Name = "TodoItems")]
  public class TodoItem
  {
     [Column]
     public string Id;
     [Column]
     public string Text;
     [Column]
     public bool Complete;
  }
  ```

  Note: TodoItems is a table your database
- HttpCSharpTrigger function

  ```
  #r "System.Data.dll"
  #r "System.Data.Linq.dll"

  #load "TodoItem.csx"

  using System.Net;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  using System.Data.Linq;

  public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage   req, TraceWriter log)
  {
       log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

       var connectionString =   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconn"].ConnectionString;
       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
       DataContext db = new DataContext(conn);
       Table<TodoItem> todoItems = db.GetTable<TodoItem>();
       IEnumerable<TodoItem> items = todoItems.ToList();

       return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, items);
  }
  ```

Note: **sqlconn** is the name of the App Setting

You will be able to call into this [API from Power Apps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-azure-functions-in-powerapps/)

Hope this helps!