# Read values from local.settings.json in VS 2017 Azure Function development

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions, appsettings

I am writing an Azure function in VS 2017. I need to set up a few custom configuration parameters. I added them in `local.settings.json` under `Values`.

```
{
   "IsEncrypted":false,
   "Values" : {
      "CustomUrl" : "www.google.com",
       "Keys": { 
           "Value1":"1",
           "Value2" :"2"
       }
   }
}
```

Now, `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CustomUrl"]` returns null.

I'm using:

- .NET Framework 4.7
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.5
- System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.4.0
- Azure.Functions.Cli 1.0.4

Am I missing something?

Comment: This should work. Can you step into debugger and see what's in `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`?

Comment: make sure `local.settings.json` is marked to always be copied to the build output.

Comment: @Mikhail -  `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` shows an object with Count = 0, KeyCollection = 0 etc..

Comment: @ahmelsayed  it's already set "Copy Always" and build action is None.

Comment: under `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli`, what versions do you have?

Comment: `Azure.Functions.Cli : 1.0.4`

Comment: It's very odd. I don't know what could be happening, but here is what **should** happen. When you run from VS, it's supposed to compile and copy all your files to the output path, something like `bin\Debug\net461`. There you should find a folder per function, and your `host.json` and `local.settings.json`. After that, VS launches `Azure.Functions.Cli.exe` from the path above, with that folder as the current working directory, and `host start` as args. That should copy all your settings from `local.settings.json` to `Azure.Functions.Cli.exe.config` in that folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156586/discussion-between-ahmelsayed-and-venky).

Comment: Nested objects in config are supported in functions v2 (Net Core) but don't seem to work in v1 (Net Framework)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Firstly, I create a sample and do a test with your **local.settings.json** data, as Mikhail and ahmelsayed said, it works fine.

Besides, as far as I know, `Values` collection is expected to be a Dictionary, if it contains any non-string values, it can cause Azure function can not read values from local.settings.json.

***My Test:***

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CustomUrl"]` returns null with the following local.settings.json.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "CustomUrl": "www.google.com",
    "testkey": {
      "name": "kname1",
      "value": "kval1"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Fred ..  I was having another object inside `Values`. My bad.

Comment: Look at the post by @Chris Koester regarding the *new* recommended way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#environment-variables

Comment: To be more precise, Azure Functions simply don't support nested settings, i.e. the `local.settings.json` file **does not** work the same as `appsettings.json` in .NET Core: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4737#issuecomment-325045802

Comment: @Venky That's true but if you want to have nested key values you can do sth like that: [nested keys](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1473#issuecomment-393303529)

Answer (score 88):

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("key")`

I was able to read values from local.settings.json using the above line of code.

Comment: Microsoft recommends this method because it works both locally with local.settings.json and in Azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#environment-variables

Comment: How do we access keys in ConnectionStrings object using Environment ?

Comment: this is the correct answer when we use function app

Answer (score 6):

Azure function copies the binaries to the bin folder and runs using the azure function cli, so it searches for the local.settings.json, so make sure you have set the `"Copy to Output Directory"` to `"Copy Always"`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you are using TimeTrigger based Azure function than you can access your key (created in local.settings.json) from Azure Function as below.

```
[FunctionName("BackupTableStorageFunction")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("%BackUpTableStorageTriggerTime%")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 6):

Using **`.Net 6`** (and probably some earlier versions) it is possible to inject `IConfiguration` into the constructor of the function.

```
public Function1(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    string setting = _configuration.GetValue<string>("MySetting");
}
```

`MySetting` must be in the `Values` section of `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "MySetting": "value"
  }
}
```

It works with Application settings in Azure Function App as well.

Comment: Azure Functions, as far as I know are static. So can you please elaborate how you are doing DI?

Comment: Functions can be instance method. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#use-injected-dependencies) link.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you mmight be able to read the properties while debugging, but once you go and try to deploy that in azure, those properties are not going to work anymore. Azure functions does not allow nested properties, you must use all of them inline in the "Values" option or in "ConnectionStrings".
Look at this documentation as reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings

Answer (score 1):

`var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("key", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);` should be the more appropriate answer, though `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process` is the default value but it's more meaningful here.

Look at its `EnvironmentVariableTarget` declaration.

```
//
// Summary:
//     Specifies the location where an environment variable is stored or retrieved in
//     a set or get operation.
public enum EnvironmentVariableTarget
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The environment variable is stored or retrieved from the environment block associated
    //     with the current process.
    Process = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The environment variable is stored or retrieved from the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
    //     key in the Windows operating system registry. This value should be used on .NET
    //     implementations running on Windows systems only.
    User = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The environment variable is stored or retrieved from the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
    //     Manager\Environment key in the Windows operating system registry. This value
    //     should be used on .NET implementations running on Windows systems only.
    Machine = 2
}
```