# Azure Functions: Configuration file for referenced assembly

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions

We have a referenced project in `azure function app` project. The referenced assembly is a `data service` project which is referred to by `web api` project too.

When referenced in `web-api` project the `data service project` automatically refers to `web.config` file for connection strings and app settings. While in `azure functions app` the `data service` project is not able to locate the connection strings stored in `local.settings.json` file.

1. How to address this issue locally?
2. How to address the issue in production?

**NOTE:** Would like to have DRY approach here.

Comment: How do you read the connection string?

Comment: I access app settings currently as ConfigurationManager.AppSetting("ss1ConnString")

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ss1ConnString"].ConnectionString`?

Comment: Ya, that's right. It is working with `web-api` project but not with `azure functions app`

Comment: How exactly are you testing? Are you running the function in the actual function host runtime (e.g. F5 in Visual Studio or )?? What does your `local.settings.json` look like?

Comment: Yes, please post the contents of the `local.settings.json` file as this should 'just work'. Do remember the `ConnectionStrings` should be placed in a different block as the `AppSettings`. Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45555781/352640

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jan V said, you could add a data connection string in json file. Besides, you could set a break point to see whether you get the 'str' value (Debug).

```
var str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

Code in local.settings.jons file:

```
 {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": 
   "your storage account connection string",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": 
"your storage account connection string"

  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
"ConnectionStringName": "Data Source=tcp:database server name,1433;Initial Catalog=database name;Integrated Security=False;User Id=user name;Password= your Password;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"  // Refer to Azure portal>SQL database> connection string
}
}
```

For more details about how to use Azure Functions to connect to an Azure SQL Database ,you could read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup).

Comment: Also add `ProviderName`