# Manage SQL connections in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-functions-runtime

I have an azure function where I am getting failure rate like below.

Host thresholds exceeded: [Connections]. For more information, see https://aka.ms/functions-thresholds.

On my initial finding I found below link
https://aka.ms/functions-thresholds

As per above link I found problem is because of **Number of outbound connections**

On my further search this could be possible because of three reasons as per below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections

Now Since I am not using any Http Client and DocumentClient  so I am sure there is something wrong with SQL connection as my Azure function calling some class libraries internally and all these libraries work with SQL.

Now as per the below documentation I am highly confused like what to in case of optimizing this.

> Some data frameworks, such as Entity Framework, typically get
>   connection strings from the ConnectionStrings section of a
>   configuration file. In this case, you must explicitly add SQL database
>   connection strings to the Connection strings collection of your
>   function app settings and in the local.settings.json file in your
>   local project. If you are creating a SqlConnection in your function
>   code, **you should store the connection string value in Application
>   settings with your other connections.**

In first paragraph it is saying store SQL connection string under **Application settings - > Connection strings collection.**

In second paragraph its saying store SQL connection string under Application setting so does my question is -  Does it means like **Application settings - > Application settings collection.**

Since all libraries which I am calling are getting connection string from configuration file with

So If I store SQL connection string under app setting then I have to change the calling style based on below setting

Can any body elaborate more where exactly store SQL connection string under the Function App setting ?

Also is there any way to use avoid below error ?

Host thresholds exceeded: [Connections]. For more information, see https://aka.ms/functions-thresholds.
Problem Id:System.InvalidOperationException at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHostManager.IsHostHealthy

Comment: My first suggestion would be reviewing your code. And then you can try to reduce WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT to a smaller number to see if the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the database connection string in the app settings in azure portal, steps as below:

1. Nav to azure portal -> your function app
2. Go to `overview` panel -> select `application settings`
   [image]
3. Under `application settings`, go to the `Connection String` node, click `add new connection string` to add your string
   [image]

For more details, refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215069/azure-functions-database-connection-string)