# Proper way of using connections string inside Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure-functions

I want to safely use database (sql server) connection string inside my app.

In the examples from [Azure github](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/tree/master/v2functions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215069/azure-functions-database-connection-string) thread it is stored inside **local.settings.json**.

What is the preferred way of getting connection string from local.settings.json file and using it to create connection?

Answer (score 0):

I made an experiment to check out how this settings works.

I added item to *Values* keys inside local.settings.json

Items from *Values* section in local.settings.json are loaded to the environment variables so I was able to use it with **os.environ** dict.

I wish all that was in some Azure Functions Python docs.