# Azure functions - How to add my database connection string in app.config

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Get the DB strings from app.config with C# in Azure function.

In the below way I am accessing the strings:

```
var Conn = ConfigurationManager
                   .ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString
```

Looking for the good method to get control of database with conn strings.

Comment: Why not put it in the Function App configuration settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Configuration Manager is recommended when using Asp.Net Core Configuration System in an azure function.

You can access it via the `GetConnectionString` from the `ConfigurationBuilder`

`var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("SqlConnectionString");`

Follow this link to add the configuration in your project - https://blog.jongallant.com/2018/01/azure-function-config/

Comment: hey, thanks.. this is helpful.. Also I've gone through another SO which is related to this question. Adding it here so that it can help someone. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215069/azure-functions-database-connection-string